# Is there a music player in 16.04 displaying the full date tag of ogg files, not only the year?

Tags: 16.04, music-player, clementine, tag, exaile

The DATE tag of most ogg files in my music collection follows ISO standard

```
 DATE=YYYY-MM-DD
```

as allowed (and even recommended) in: https://wiki.xiph.org/VorbisComment#Date_and_time .

I used to play these files with Exaile, which displays this information in full, allowing me to sort the playlist in chronological order.

Unfortunately Exaile was removed from 16.04. I tried other music players (Amarok, Audacious, Banshee, Clementine, Rythmbox...) but as far as I can tell, all of them seem to automatically shorten the displayed date information YYYY-MM-DD into 'year-only' YYYY.

In fact this is not only a display problem. Now sorting by 'year-only' with these players breaks the correct chronological order.

Is there an alternative to Exaile that would display the full date as YYYY-MM-DD, not only the year? Is there an option I missed in the aforementioned players that would turn them in working this way? Is there another way to work this around? I really do not want to re-tag all my files.